# Select by SQL in QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, query, select-by-attribute

In the GUI there is the Query Builder, but that does not seem to be easily available in Python. The processing (SEXTANTE) module has the `qgis:selectbyattribute` algorithm, but that only supports selecting by a single attribute. There is also `QgsFeatureRequest.setFilterExpression`, but apparently that is not available in current stable version (2.0.1 Dufour).

Do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is listed in the pyqgis cookbook.

[PyQGIS Developer Cookbook 2.18](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)

[PyQGIS Developer Cookbook 3](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)

You need to make use of the optional where clause.

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "johny", "xxx")
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionaly
# subset (WHERE clause)
uri.setDataSource("public", "roads", "the_geom", "cityid = 2643")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "layer_name_you_like", "postgres")
```

Or if you want to filter an existing layer, you can use setSubsetString from QgsVectorLayer

http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a6ad141dfa9a0243c0c1c9fa422379e40

Comment: Thanks, that'll work nicely! Only for vector layers, I guess, but that's all I need.